# Scala Convert a Variable to Future?

Tags: scala

I have a `case class User` and I want to return it as `Future[User]`. But when I do the same I get this error:

`No implicits found for parameter executor: ExecutionContext`

Can someone help me with the right syntax to convert a non future result to future return type?

Comment: If you have an already computed value and only want to create an already completed future just to satisfy the type system then use `Future.succesful` which doesn't require an execution context. If rather you want to submit some computation that will yield such value then you should ask for an implicit execution context for the caller to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't define an `ExecutionContext` elsewhere, you can use Scala's global `ExecutionContext` with either:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

or:

```scala
implicit val ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext = 
  scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
```

Comment: Which one is more optimized? Second right?

Comment: @ShivamSahil Quoting the documentation, the first is `An accessor that can be used to import the global ExecutionContext into the implicit scope (...)`, so I'd guess they're rather synonymous (but I'm not 100% sure in that matter)

Comment: It depends on your requirements: if you need it in a few places (source files), you can just import it. If you need it in a lot of places (or you need your custom `ExecutionContext`), defining an implicit `ExecutionContext` is better.

Comment: Warning: using the default `ExecutionContext` is often not a good thing. It all depends on your context (a webapp? A processing script..?)